# How do I raise a float to an exponent in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to write a function that takes x and raises it to the power of n.

This code works if x and n are integers:

```
let rec pow x n =
if n == 0 then 1 else
if (n mod 2 = 0) then pow x (n/2) * pow x (n/2) else
x * pow x (n/2) * pow x (n/2);;
```

If I try to change the code to work if x is a float, it falls apart:

```
let rec float_pow x n =
if n == 0.0 then 1.0 else
if n mod_float 2.0 == 0.0 then float_pow x (n /. 2) *. float_pow x (n /. 2) else
x *. float_pow x (n /. 2) *. float_pow x (n /. 2);;
```

I get this error:

```
Error: This expression has type float
   This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

What do I do?

Comment: For those who just want to raise a value to an exponent in OCaml, the corresponding operator is called `**` in OCaml, therefore `x^n` is coded as `x ** n`, e.g., `2.0 ** 3.14`.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem, I think, is that `mod` is a keyword in OCaml, and is treated as an infix operator. But `mod_float` is just an ordinary function. You need to use it in prefix form.

So `x mod n` should be translated to `mod_float x n`.

You have another problem, which is that you're using the special-purpose `==` operator for equality comparison. You want to use `=` for equality comparisons in OCaml unless you need a "physical" comparison (which is not what you want here).

This isn't just stylistic--it really makes a difference. Note the following results:

```
# 0.0 == 0.0;;
- : bool = false
# 0.0 = 0.0;;
- : bool = true
```